# Is the latest javax.servlet.jsp jsp-api version in maven stable?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, version

I'm now working on version up the maven dependencies in our application.
I was searching around for the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the central maven repository I was finding the last version which is 2.2.1-b03. This version was added at Jan 10, 2011, so more then 4 years ago.

Is this beta version stable enough to use it in a complex application? Or should I use the version 2.2? Or is there any other groupId/artifactId which is more up to date for this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if this could help you, but there is also a: javax.servlet.jsp-api under the same group and the first version starts where jsp-api ends. Maybe it is useful for you and is newer (april 2013), and there is beta of 2014 too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp